# How to print the contents of a 2-D array using an overloaded function in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm taking a Java Programming Class, and I'm currently working on a portfolio. Usually, I am able to complete these, but the portfolio to help learn about arrays is serving as a big challenge. I've been stuck on a specific step (step 5,b,ii) for a while now, and I seriously can't find any solutions. There was one forum post from someone who had a pretty similar set of steps from a few years back, but the solutions didn't help. These are the steps so far:

1. Start a program in a class named `ArrayPrinter`. Ignore the main method for a moment.
2. In your class, create a static method named `printArray` with one parameter of type `int[]` named `arr`. Inside this method, do the following:

   a. Keep all of your output in this method on one line using System.out.print() until directed to use `println()`.
   b. Display an opening square bracket character.
   c. Loop through the array that was passed into the method. Display the values in the array. Add a comma and a space after every value except the last one.
   d. Using `System.out.println()`, display a closing square bracket character.
3. In your main method, create the following array:

   `int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};`

Pass the reference to this array to the `printArray` method, run your program, and verify it works as expected. (Note. This worked as expected.)

4. In your main method, add a blank `println()` statement after the method calls you just made.
5. In the class, create an overloaded static method named `printArray` with one parameter of type `int[][]` named `arr`. Inside this method, do the following:

   a. Using `println()`, display an opening square bracket character.
   b. Loop through the two-dimensional array that was passed into the method.
   i. First, use System.out.print() to display two space characters.
   ii. Every element of this two-dimensional array that you are looping through is a one-dimensional array of int. Call the other `printArray` method and pass it to each one-dimensional array in the two-dimensional array.
   c. Using `println()`, display a closing square bracket character.
6. In your main method, create the following two-dimensional array. Pass the reference to this array to the `printArray` method, run your program, and verify that it works as expected.
7. In your main method, add a blank `println()` statement after the method calls you just made.

There are a few more steps after this, but this is where I stopped to try and figure out what was wrong. As said before, my main problem is for step 5, b, ii. It says to call the other `printArray` method and pass it to the loop in the two-dimensional `printArray` method. This is where I'm lost. I still did steps 6 and 7, but I can't go any further without making sure this works.

Someone with a similar project for Java (but a bit different too) had a problem on the same step as I. The response was to use the line:

```
print(int[] arr);
```

I tried that, but got the two errors:

> "The method print(int[]::arr) is undefined for the type ArrayPrinter"
>   and "Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token"

```
public class ArrayPrinter {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};
    printArray(oneD);
    System.out.println();
    int[][] twoD = {{2, 4, 6, 8},
                   {8, 7, 9, 1},
                   {3, 5, 1, 2}};
    printArray(twoD);

}

public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i < arr.length -1) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
    System.out.println("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < arr[i].length; i2++) {
            System.out.print("  ");


        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

}

If there was no error, it should've printed something like:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[8, 7, 9, 1]
[3, 5, 1, 2]
]
```

But instead, it only printed:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I also got the error messages I showed above my code.

Comment: For printing the 2-D array, you can simply pass the the `printArray(int[] arr)` method inside the loop in the `printArray(int[][] arr)` method like `printArr(arr[i])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `printArray(int[][] arr)` function, remove the inner loop and replace it with `printArray(arr[i])` and it will do the job.
Essentially, a 2-D array is an array where the elements of the array are 1-D arrays itself. You already have a working function that prints a 1-D array so simply iterate the 2-D array on the outer loop and then call the function to print the 1-D array for each element. This way, you have less code and less code means less places for bugs to lurk around.

Comment: @JohnyWilburg DRY, remember it

Answer (score 1):

```
package data.structures;

public class LinkedListRunner {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};
        printArray(oneD);
        System.out.println();
        int[][] twoD = {{2, 4, 6, 8},
                       {8, 7, 9, 1},
                       {3, 5, 1, 2}};
        printArray(twoD);

    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(i < arr.length -1) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {

        System.out.println(" [ ");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i][j] + " ");
             }
            System.out.println("]");
             }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

}


Output:
[5, 6, 7, 8]
 [ 
[ 2  4  6  8 ]
[ 8  7  9  1 ]
[ 3  5  1  2 ]
 ]
```

You can try that out the problem was with the print out.you actually created a two dimensional array param but didn't print it out with the indexes values that iterates through the row and column...So that was basically the error.This:System.out.print(" " + arr[i][j] + " ");

Comment: You can reduce some lines of codes by simply calling the `printArray()` function for the 1-D array inside the first loop in like `printArray(arr[i])` and getting rid of the inner loop. Also, I edited your answer and removed most of the unnecessary part.